# R - Files not found when call to import folder, but open as individual files and list.files shows all?

Tags: r

I have a bit of code used successfully before. It should import all files in a given directory into a single dataset. I have a new folder of data, and now I can't get it to work. The individual files will read in. List.files will also show all files in the folder. So I'm at a loss.

```
list.files('../data/')
[1] "B101-2.txt" "B101.txt"   "B116.txt"   "B6.txt"     "B65.txt"    "B67-2.txt"  "B67.txt"   
[8] "B70.txt"    "B71-2.txt"  "B71.txt"    "B95-2.txt"  "B95.txt"    "B96-2.txt"  "B96.txt"   
[15] "B98-2.txt"  "B98.txt"    "B99-2.txt"  "B99.txt"   

a = ldply(
.data = list.files(
    path = '../data/'
        )
, .fun = function(x){
    from_header = scan(x,n = 1,skip=1,quiet=T)
    to_return = read.table(
        file = x
        , skip = 20
        , sep = '\t'
        , fill = TRUE
            )
    to_return$condition = from_header[1]
    return(to_return)
        }
, .progress = 'text'
)
```

> Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In file(file, "r") :
>     cannot open file 'B101-2.txt': No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the full path name can be done in `list.files` directly.

```
list.files(path = '../data', full.names = TRUE)
```

Note the omission of `/` in the path specification. If left in, the files would be listed as `..data//B101-2.txt`, which would fail.

**TEST** Simulating a file structure you note in [Tim Biegeleisen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38006691/5967807):

```
library(plyr)
dir.create("analysis")
dir.create("data")
write.table(matrix(c(1:57,1:6), ncol=3, byrow=T), file="data/test1.txt", sep="\t", row.names=F, quote=F)
write.table(matrix(c(2:58,7:12), ncol=3, byrow=T), file="data/test2.txt", sep="\t", row.names=F, quote=F)
write.table(matrix(c(3:59,13:18), ncol=3, byrow=T), file="data/test3.txt", sep="\t", row.names=F, quote=F)
```

We now run your code from within the analysis folder.

```
setwd("analysis")
a = ldply(
.data = list.files(path = '../data', full.names = TRUE)
, .fun = function(x){
    from_header = scan(x,n = 1,skip=1,quiet=T)
    to_return = read.table(file = x, skip = 20, sep = '\t', fill = TRUE)
    to_return$condition = from_header[1]
    return(to_return)
        }
, .progress = 'text'
)
```

The code reads in all three files and outputs lines 21-22 for each.

```
a
  V1 V2 V3 condition
1  1  2  3         1
2  4  5  6         1
3  7  8  9         2
4 10 11 12         2
5 13 14 15         3
6 16 17 18         3
```

Comment: @OrianeLandry This reads all necessary files in my dummy example. Is your working directory set to e.g. "test/analysis" where your data would be in "test/data" as you described at the TimBiegeleisen's answer?

Comment: yes, the working directory is "test/analysis". Same error message.

Answer (score 0):

`list.files('../data/')` is showing you output like `B101-2.txt` etc. for the files, but from your very call to `list.files()` you can see that the relative path is `../data/`.  So if you were to try to do, for example, `read.csv(file="B101-2.txt")` it would fail.  Instead, the call should be `read.csv(file="../data/B101-2.txt")`.  The solution to your problem is to use the full relative path necessary to address the files.

Use this as the first argument to `ldply()`:

```
.data = paste0("../data/", list.files(path = '../data/'))
```

The key thing to take away from this is that `list.files()` returns a list of *filenames* (with extensions), not the full or relative path to those files.

Comment: This did not solve the problem. The file structure is one of project with subfolders of analysis and data, which is why the "../data/" to go up a level and down into the data folder. I can read an individual file. It's the call to read the whole folder that fails. It will be a pain to have to read them in one by one.

Comment: Give me the relative path of a single file which you can read.

Comment: `list.files('../data/')`
 [1] "B101.txt"  ... it works
` to_return = read.table(
    file = '../data/B101.txt'
    , skip = 20
    , sep = '\t'
    , fill = TRUE
     )`
This worked, but when I try the function to read all the files I get: 
Error in file(file, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "r") : cannot open file 'B101.txt': No such file or directory